# How to animate item placement without using animateItemPlacement()

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a complex compose layout where I render different UI components in a single lazy columns. Since I can't do nested lazy column without defining fixed height for the child lazy column, which I don't want to do.

One of the child UI component hosts rows (max 3). It's basically a column that I add three rows to it as I get data and the rows content keep changing as we get data
I wanted to achieve something similar that animateItemPlacement() offers as when a new row is added it animates the whole list,  but since I am not using lazy column I am unable to achieve this. Trying to find an alternative to achieve this sort of animation without lazy column scope

Comment: To further explain what I want, I want create a rolling stack with three items visible all the time, when a new item is add it comes from the top of the stack while the last item exits the view. This all without the LazyColumn

Answer (score 0):

try to use this `modifier` in your `Column`

> The `animateContentSize` modifier animates a size change.

```kotlin
Column(modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()) {
  ...
}
```

> Note: The ordering of where `animateContentSize` is placed in your modifier chain matters. For smooth animations, ensure you place it before any size modifiers such as `size` or `defaultMinSize` to ensure that `animateContentSize` reports the animated value change to the Layout.

Also you can read this [Built-in animation modifiers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animation-modifiers)